# Redefine memoir Part to allow image

Tags: sectioning, graphics, memoir, parts

I am preparing a book with `memoir`. The book has three parts. I would like to have the Part title raised and to insert an image directly below the title. I am able to raise the Part title to the upper portion of the page, and to add an image, but the image falls on the following (normally blank) page (see minimum example, below).

How can I get the image to appear on the same page as the Part title, directly under it?

Here is the minimum example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{memoir} %
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\beforepartskip}{\null\vskip-2cm}
\renewcommand*{\afterpartskip}{\par\vskip-5cm%
\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

% \frontmatter
%
%
% \mainmatter

\part{This is the first part}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
% By default, eso-pic's zero coordinate is in the lower left corner
\put(\LenToUnit{3.5in},\LenToUnit{5.5in}){%
\includegraphics[height=25mm,keepaspectratio]{figs/PA-500942}%
}
}

\part{This is the second part}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Using the same technique as in this question [Adding a figure to a Part Page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27032/2693) it's much easier to do with `memoir`:

First we define a command to set the image name for each part. This command takes the same arguments as the `\includegraphics` command from the `graphicx` package. Then we add the image to the `memoir` class `\printparttitle` command.  You can play with the `\vfil` commands to change the vertical spacing as you require it.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\makeatletter
% define a user command to choose the image
% this command also creates an internal command to insert the image
\def\@partimage{}
\newcommand{\partimage}[2][]{\gdef\@partimage{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{\parttitlefont #1\vfil\@partimage\vfil\gdef\@partimage{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\partimage{foo.png}
\part{A part}
\partimage[width=\textwidth]{bar.png}
\part{Another part}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of first part page]

Comment: This is wonderful. Thanks very much for this answer!

Comment: LaTeX newbie here. Your example code works nicely with `pdflatex`. However, my project has subfiles. I inserted the code between `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` in the top-level main file and then I get the error `! Undefined control sequence.
\printparttitle ...ttitlefont #1\vfil \@partimage 
                                                  \vfil 
` when compiling. What am I missing? Thx

Comment: @LaryxDecidua Without some code it's hard to tell. What do you mean by "subfiles"? Are you using the `subfiles` package or just `\input` and/or `\include`?  And are you *are* using the `memoir` class, right?

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, it's the `memoir` class, with the `subfiles` package. Can't really insert much code in a comment though. Will send you PM with more details if you don't mind. thx

Comment: @LaryxDecidua There's no PM on the site, and solving problems privately isn't practical. It would be best then to make a minimal document like the example in the answer but using a sample `subfile` and ask a new question, linking to this question.

Comment: @LaryxDecidua You can add `\gdef\@partimage{}` after the second `\vfil`, so a missing `\partimage` before a subsequent `\part` command will get things back on track and nothing will be printed.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for this. I've  added that to the answer.

Comment: Thx, but no good: `! Undefined control sequence.
\printparttitle ...ttitlefont #1\vfil \@partimage 
                                                  \vfil \gdef \@partimage {}
l.15 \part{A part}
`

Comment: @LaryxDecidua See edit. Add `\def\@partimage{}` before the definition of `\partimage`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but rather a follow-up to my comments to @Alan Munn's answer. I made it an answer so that I can include code examples.

My problem was not that I used the `subfiles` package, but rather the fact that I did not always add an image to the part page. Here is a simplified example: the part page includes an image and it works as advertised (practically the same as Alan's example):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\makeatletter
% define a user command to choose the image
% this command also creates an internal command to insert the image
\newcommand{\partimage}[2][]{\gdef\@partimage{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{\parttitlefont #1\vfil\@partimage\vfil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\partimage{foo.png} % this works beautifully!
\part{A part}
Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

However, if I *comment out* the `\partimage` command because I do not want to add any images to the Part page:

```
...
\begin{document}
%%%%% \partimage{foo.png}
\part{A part}
Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

then I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\printparttitle ...ttitlefont #1\vfil \@partimage 
                                                  \vfil 
l.15 \part{A part}
```

This probably happens because `\printparttitle` expects a `\partimage`, or so it seems to me (please correct if I am wrong here).

As I am new to LaTeX, I cannot propose an elegant solution. Possible hacks: One could invoke `\partimage{some_dummy_image.jpg}` with the dummy image being a 10x10 pixel white box. Or maybe one can rewrite the `\partimage` command so that it does nothing if invoked as `\partimage{}` (this I can't do due to lack of knowledge).

Summary: use Alan's solution if you *always* decorate the Parts pages with images.

Comment: See my comment to Alan Munn's answer.