# Redefine report Part with image

Tags: graphics, sectioning, parts

I am trying to include an image on the part title page of my report, so that it looks like this, but shows up correctly in the ToC:

```
\clearpage
\newpage
{\pagestyle{empty} \enlargethispage{10\baselineskip}
{\huge\textbf{Part I: Lorem Ipsum}}\\
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/part_1_title.pdf}
\end{center}
\clearpage}
\newpage
```

A similar question has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40602/redefine-memoir-part-to-allow-image), but for me the `\printparttitle` produces an error.

Does someone know how to do this?

An other similar question was asked in an other forum: [here](http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/personnaliser-la-page-d-une-nouvelle-partie-en-mode-book-t8212.html).

I tried to modify the defnition of `\part` from the `report.cls` file to actually get the title of the Part to look different, but it didn't work. (I need the space for the picture).

What it looks like:
**Part I

Lorem Ipsum**

What I want it to look like
**Part I: Lorem Ipsum**
which is obtained by this code:

```
{\pagestyle{empty} \enlargethispage{10\baselineskip}
{\huge\textbf{Part I: Lorem ipsum}}\\
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/PartI_Loerm.pdf}
\end{center}
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: If you want to change the appearance of the part title you shouldn't remove `\@spart`, but only modify the definition of `\@part`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the image typesetting to the command `\@endpart`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\imagepart}[1]{\def\@theimagepart{#1}\part}
\def\@endpart{%
  \par\medskip
  \hrule
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\@theimagepart}
  \end{center}
  \vfil\newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright
      \null
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Complete example (the `demo` option is just for the example)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\imagepart}[1]{\def\@theimagepart{#1}\part}
\def\@endpart{%
  \par\medskip
  \hrule
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\@theimagepart}
  \end{center}
  \vfil\newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright
      \null
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\imagepart{figures/part_1_title.pdf}{Part title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible redefinition also of `\@part`, with some minor modifications to `\@endpart`, in order not to have line breaks in the title.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\imagepart}[1]{\def\@theimagepart{#1}\part}
\def\@endpart{%
  \par\vskip12pt\hrule\vskip12pt
  {\centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\@theimagepart}\par}
  \vfil\newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright
      \null
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi}
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  \fi
  \markboth{}{}%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
     \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart: 
   \fi
   #2\par}
  \@endpart}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\imagepart{figures/part_1_title.pdf}{Part title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to move up the part title, you have to change the `\vfil` in the definition of `\part`; for instance, by adding

```
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vspace{\stretch{1}}
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
```

and changing the `\vfil` in the redefinition of `\@endpart` to `\vspace{\stretch{2}}` you'll have twice as much space at the bottom than at the top.

---

## Final version

Left of the picture the result of `\imagepart`, right your wish.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\imagepart}[1]{\def\@theimagepart{#1}\part}
\def\@endpart{%
  \par\vskip12pt\hrule\vskip12pt
  {\centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\@theimagepart}\par}
  \vfil\newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright
      \null
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi}
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vspace{-2\baselineskip}
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  \fi
  \markboth{}{}%
  {\raggedright
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
     \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart: 
   \fi
   #2\par}
  \@endpart}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\imagepart{figures/part_1_title.pdf}{Part title}

\clearpage
\newpage
{\pagestyle{empty} \enlargethispage{10\baselineskip}
{\huge\textbf{Part I: Lorem Ipsum}}\\
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/part_1_title.pdf}
\end{center}
\clearpage}
\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Addition 2022

How to add some description text below the image? Here's a possibility.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\imagepart}[2]{%
  \def\@theimagepart{#1}%
  \def\@thecaptionpart{#2}%
  \part
}

\def\@endpart{%
  \par\medskip
  \hrule
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\@theimagepart} \\
  \@thecaptionpart
  \end{center}
  \vfil\newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright
      \null
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\imagepart{example-image}{Description}{Part title}

\end{document}
```

Apply the formatting you wish around the call of `\@thecptionpart`.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for addidng that! Now there is just the problem of the picture getting to a new page after the title. So I skipped th `hrule`, but even that would not help.

Comment: `\enlargethispage{5\baselineskip}` helps, but it does not solve the problem. - How can I bring the \part further up? I tried a \vspace{-5em}, but it would produce errors:
`\newcommand{\imagepart}[1]{\def\@theimagepart{#1}\vspace{-5em}\part}`
I guess, I need to revert the effect of `\vskip 20` in the `part` definition?

Comment: @Jonas Rather than shooting at random, why don't you add to your question the precise specifications of what you wish?

Comment: Good point! I tried to do this now. :)

Comment: Hi egreg, do you know how to create this with caption to the image?

Comment: @Fraïssé Ihope you don’t want a numbered caption…

Comment: Hi egreg, oh no, it is just I have multiple parts and want multiple images underneath, each with a short explanatory caption. However right now \imagepart is defined on top of \part, so that all these parts are basically the same.

Comment: @Fraïssé I added the basic scheme.

Comment: Marvelous, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a KOMA class you can do this by `\setpartpreamble`. The command has two optional arguments to specify the position and width.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\setpartpreamble{%
\begin{center}
Here some text and a picture

\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{center}
}
\part{foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!