# memoir: Adding text below part title?

Tags: memoir, parts

I would like to be able to add a bit of text below the title on a part page. Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40612/18181) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40602/18181), I came up with

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\makeatletter
\def\@parttext{}
\newcommand{\parttext}[1]{\gdef\@parttext{\normalsize\normalfont\justify #1}}
\renewcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{\parttitlefont #1\vfil\@parttext\vfil\gdef\@parttext{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\parttext{\lipsum[1-2]}
\part{This is part one}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

but I must admit that I do not fully understand what is going on, so I would be glad for feedback on how to improve the new and renewed commands.

**EDIT:** One aspect of the renewed command that bothers me is that even if I do not add any text, the part number and title are moved up. How can I avoid this?

Comment: I don't understand what problem there is with using a command that works, even if you don't understand how it does, but if this obfuscates you, a simple option is the `article` class: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\part{This in part one}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}`

Comment: @Fran: I did not say there is a problem; I just want to understand whether it can be improved. Getting feedback from more experienced people is one way to learn. Switching to the `article` class is not an option; my entire document is in `memoir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way to do this by redefining the `\partpageend` macro but I'm not going to go into that.

In the solution you presented the `\parttext` macro creates the `\@parttext` macro holding the formatted text to be printed after the part title.

The `\printparttitle` macro, which prints the part number and title, is extended to call `\@parttext` to print the after-title text. The `\vfil` macros vertically center the text between the title and the bottom of the textblock, and then finally emptying `\@parttext`.

I'm not sure that it can be improved; it works.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the answer - and thanks for putting the memoir package together, I like using it a lot!