# Adding an image to the same page as \part with book class?

Tags: graphics, parts, book-class

I love using LaTeX but suck with code. I see answers to my question for [memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40602/redefine-memoir-part-to-allow-image) and [amsbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27032/adding-a-figure-to-a-part-page) classes, but I am not clever enough to adapt that code to book class. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is the same as for `amsbook` but you need to copy the relevant code from `book.cls`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\@partimage{}
\newcommand{\partimage}[2][]{\gdef\@partimage{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\vfil\@partimage\vfil\par}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\partimage[]{example-image-duck.pdf} % same arguments as \includegraphics
\part{Part Title (Figure Below)}   
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

If you want the image centred between the title and the bottom of the page, replace both instances of `\vfil` with `\vfill`.

Now I have the trifecta for this question. :)

[image: output of code]